# Matching multiple DataItems using .getDataItems

Tags: wear-os

I have data items stored with the path `/item/<id>`. I'm trying to get all current items stored in the network using `Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems(GoogleApiClient, Uri)`, but passing in the uri with the `/item/` path doesn't match anything. I've checked to make sure the hosts match up.

The [Android Wear documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataApi.html#getDataItems(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20android.net.Uri)) says that:

> if the host is elided, all data items matching that path are returned.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Uri.parse("wear:/item")`?

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataApi.html